# pausing and unpausing a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having trouble understanding how `locks`, the `wait` method and the `notify` method appear to work.

So from what I understand, if call `x.wait()` on a thread, it will wait until another thread calls `x.notify()`. From then on, everything will go on the way it normally would. What my code is supposed to do is simply print `i` in the thread, then pause and wait until the thread is notified. However something is going wrong. Am I using a wrong lock?

```
class X {
        private Thread thread;
        private boolean isPaused;

        public X() {
            isPaused = false;

            this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public synchronized void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        pause();
                        waitTillUnpaused();

                    }
                }
            });

            System.out.println("Starting the thread");
            this.thread.start();


            unpause();

            waitTillPaused();
            unpause();

            waitTillPaused();
            unpause();

            waitTillPaused();
            unpause();

            waitTillPaused();
            unpause();

            waitTillPaused();
            unpause();

            System.out.println("End");
        }

        public void waitTillUnpaused() {
            synchronized (thread) {
                try {
                    while (isPaused) {
                        thread.wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            synchronized (thread) {
                isPaused = true;
            }
        }

        public void waitTillPaused() {
            synchronized (thread) {
                while (!isPaused) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void unpause() {
            synchronized(thread){
                isPaused = false;
                thread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to call `wait` in `waitTillPaused`. You just hold the lock and spin, making it impossible for any other thread to pause you. (Also, if you want to be able to wait until you're paused, then `pause` has to call `notifyAll` too.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you using a wrong lock. change your code:

```
    private volatile boolean isPaused;
...
    public void waitTillPaused() {
            while (!isPaused) {
            }
    }
```

To the following:

```
   public void pause() {
        synchronized (thread) {  // lock thread
            isPaused = true;
        }
    }

    public void waitTillPaused() { // lock thread
        synchronized (thread) {
            while (!isPaused) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Method `waitTillPaused` locks the thread, and method `pause` `wait` unlock forever, it's a dead lock. When you use `wait` it unlocks the thread, but if you use the following:

```
synchronized (thread) {
      while (!isPaused) {
      }
}
```

The thread isn't unlocked at all.